# Insert matrix values based on exact row/column names

Tags: r, matrix, merge

I have a blank matrix with row and column names that is relatively large (6000 times 200). Then, I have multiple matrices which represent subsets of this matrix (typically around 1500 times 120) and also contain row and column names. I want to insert the information from the cells in a given subsets into the blank matrix based on the combination of row/column name.

Here is an example of the data and the desired output:

```
adj1 <- matrix(0, 3, 4)
colnames(adj1) <- c("g1", "g2", "g3", "g4")
rownames(adj1) <- c("Tim", "John", "Sarah")

adj2 <- matrix(0, 2, 2)
colnames(adj2) <- c("g1", "g4")
rownames(adj2) <- c("Tim", "John")
adj2[1,2] <- 1
adj2

combined_adj <- matrix(0,3,4)
colnames(combined_adj) <- c("g1","g2","g3","g4")
rownames(combined_adj) <- c("Tim","John", "Sarah")
combined_adj[1,4] <- 1
combined_adj
```

I have somewhat managed to intersect by column names, but not by the exact combination of row/col names.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a function that allows you to replace values by row and column names.
Its arguments are

- `x` the larger matrix;
- `y` the matrix with new values;
- `z` the target matrix; if missing a new matrix of zeros will be created with the dimensions and row/col names of `x`.

```r
matreplace <- function(x, y, z){
  if(missing(z)) {
    z <- x
    z[] <- 0
  }
  ij <- Map(intersect, dimnames(z), dimnames(y))
  i <- ij[[1L]]
  j <- ij[[2L]]
  z[i, j] <- y[i, j]
  z
}

adj1 <- matrix(0, 3, 4)
colnames(adj1) <- c("g1", "g2", "g3", "g4")
rownames(adj1) <- c("Tim", "John", "Sarah")

adj2 <- matrix(0, 2, 2)
colnames(adj2) <- c("g1", "g4")
rownames(adj2) <- c("Tim", "John")
adj2[1,2] <- 1

combined_adj <- matreplace(adj1, adj2)

adj2[2, 1] <- pi
matreplace(adj1, adj2, combined_adj)
#>             g1 g2 g3 g4
#> Tim   0.000000  0  0  1
#> John  3.141593  0  0  0
#> Sarah 0.000000  0  0  0
```

<sup>Created on 2023-05-07 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Answer (score 2):

Here are two more alternatives:

```
# Create blank matrix
adj1 <- matrix(0, 3, 4)
colnames(adj1) <- c("g1", "g2", "g3", "g4")
rownames(adj1) <- c("Tim", "John", "Sarah")

# Create subset matrix
adj2 <- matrix(0, 2, 2)
colnames(adj2) <- c("g1", "g4")
rownames(adj2) <- c("Tim", "John")

# change and test
adj2[1,2] <- 1
adj2[2, 1] <- pi
```

#### for loop

```
# solution 1 for loop
# Fill in values in blank matrix based on row and column names
for (i in rownames(adj2)) {
  for (j in colnames(adj2)) {
    adj1[i,j] <- adj2[i,j]
  }
}
adj1
```

#### match()

```
# solution 2 using `match()`
row_idx <- match(rownames(adj2), rownames(adj1))
col_idx <- match(colnames(adj2), colnames(adj1))

adj1[row_idx, col_idx] <- adj2
adj1
```

#### output

```
            g1 g2 g3 g4
Tim   0.000000  0  0  1
John  3.141593  0  0  0
Sarah 0.000000  0  0  0
```